# Adding a callback to a class function in swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

In my project I created a public class to handle my network interfacing for data requests (JSON, images, etc). The function inside of the class uses Alamofire to establish a network connect and download the JSON file.

The class and the function are below:

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

public class DataConnectionManager {

    public class func getJSON(AppModule:String, callback:(Int) -> Void) -> Void {

        switch(AppModule) {

        case "Newsfeed":
            Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://some-site.com/api/", encoding: .JSON).responseJSON { (_, _, JSONData, _) in
                if JSONData != nil {
                    jsonHolder.jsonData = JSONData!
                    print("start")
                    callback(1)
                }
                else {
                    callback(0)
                }
            }
            break

        default:
            break

        }

    }

}
```

I call the function in my project as seen below:

```
DataConnectionManager.getJSON("Newsfeed", callback: { (intCheck : Int) -> Void in
    if intCheck == 1 {
        println("Success")
    }
    else {
        println("Failure")
    }  
})
```

The app will launch without any errors, however my sanity checks don't print out. In fact, when I do it this way the Alamofire.request doesn't grab the JSON feed either.

Am I heading in the right direction with this?

Comment: Have you try to debug it? Was it going to the Newsfeed?

Comment: Just as a matter of style, don't use upper case letters for variable names.  `JSONData` looks like a type, whereas `jsonData` looks like a variable.  I know it's a bit ambiguous in the case of a variable which begins with an acronym, but Swift, more so than most languages, has ALL types uppercase and ALL variables lowercase.

Comment: You're throwing away the error from `responseJSON` if there is one. Try parsing it instead `(_, _, JSONData, error)` `if error != nil`.

Comment: You should be wrapping your url in NSURL and not just entering a string.

Comment: Another aside: the `break` statements are superfluous. Swift breaks automatically. You need `fallthrough` to get usual C-behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, guys. I changed JSONData variable to responseData.

I also added the "error checking" portion into the Alamo request. Suddenly everything is working now.

I have no clue what was changed that fixed it, but.... it's working. I'll my updated code as the answer. If someone can review it and let me know if they see an obvious reason, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work, but I'm not sure how, exactly. I changed a couple of things based on user suggestions (adding error checking, etc) and it magically started working. Here's my updated code so people can see how to add a callback to their functions.

My "ConnectionManager":

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

public class DataConnectionManager {

    public class func getJSON(AppModule:String, callback:(Int) -> Void) -> Void {

        switch(AppModule) {

        case "Newsfeed":
            Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://some-site.com/api/", encoding: .JSON).responseJSON { (_, _, alamoResponse, error) in
                if (error != nil){
                    println("You've got a response error!")
                    callback(0)
                }
                else {
                    if alamoResponse != nil {
                        jsonHolder.jsonData = alamoResponse!
                        callback(1)
                    }
                    else {
                        println("You've got some random error")
                        callback(0)
                    }
                }
            }
            break

        default:
            break

        }

    }

}
```

My call to the function:

```
DataConnectionManager.getJSON("Newsfeed", callback: { (intCheck : Int) -> Void in
    if intCheck == 1 {
        self.createTable()
    }
    else {
        println("Failure")
    } 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using swift 2.0 + SwiftyJSON and this is my code to implement this:

```
 class func getJSON(AppModule:String, urlToRequest: String, resultJSON:(JSON) -> Void) -> Void {
    var returnResult: JSON = JSON.nullJSON

    switch(AppModule) {
    case "all":
        request(.GET, urlToRequest)
            .responseJSON { (_, _, result) in
            if (result.isFailure){
                print("You've got a response error!")
                resultJSON(nil)
            }
            else {
                if (JSON(result.value!) != nil) {
                    returnResult = JSON(result.value!)
                    resultJSON(returnResult)
                }
                else {
                    print("You've got some random error")
                }
            }
        }
        break

    default:
        break

    }

}
```

And call the function like this:

```
    DataManager.getJSON("all",urlToRequest: "myurl.com", resultJSON: { (result: JSON) -> Void in
        if (result == nil){
            // error with result json == nil
            return
        }else{
            //do something with json result
        }
    })
```

Hope this can be helpful.